# get an error before I go further in the code

Tags: php, mysqli

this is how I get the download category down from the database and then use the opportunity to click on 3 of them, for example if I take 2 of them and click on them and click on the last but go into the html code and write in value = "Hello", then write it into the database even though I have not entered the words in the database.

The problem is how do I do it only be those in which I have written here:

```
$godkendteKategorier = array("Frontend", "Backend", "Design");
        $kategorier = explode(",", $_POST["kategori"]);
        foreach($kategorier as $kategori)
        {
            if(!in_array($kategori, $godkendteKategorier))
            {
                echo "error";
            }
        }
```

It should be such that it will only go ahead if these fit together all the code that I write before, but it should not proceed to the second part of the code if there are errors the other!

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["opret"]))
{
if($_POST["title"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at skrive title!";
}
elseif($_POST["tekst"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at skrive tekst!";
}
elseif($_POST["kategori"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at angive kategori!";
}
elseif($_POST["point"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at angive point!";
}
else
{

    //find out if there are errors here!!
    $godkendteKategorier = array("Frontend", "Backend", "Design");
    $kategorier = explode(",", $_POST["kategori"]);
    foreach($kategorier as $kategori)
    {
        if(!in_array($kategori, $godkendteKategorier))
        {
            echo "error!";
        }
    }


$arr = array(60, 40, 20, 10);
$point = implode($_POST["point"]);

    if(in_array($point, $arr))
    {
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `bruger` SET `point`= `point` - ? WHERE `id`=?')) { 
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $point, $id);
            $point = implode($_POST["point"]);
            $id = $_SESSION["id"];
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }

        $str = $_POST["title"];
        $from = array("=", "+", "&",'"', "'", " ", "æ", "Æ", "ø", "Ø", "å", "Å");
        $to = array("-", "", "og", "", "", "-", "ae", "Ae", "oe", "Oe", "aa", "Aa");
        $alias = strtolower(str_replace($from, $to, $str));

        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO artikler (title, tekst, kategori, url, skrevet_af, emne, dato) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) { 

            /* Bind parametre */
            $stmt->bind_param('sssssii', $title, $tekst, $kategori, $url, $skrevet_af, $emne, $dato);

            /* Sæt værdier på parametrene */
            $title = $_POST['title']; 
            $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];
            $kategori = implode(",",$_POST["kategori"]);
            $url = $alias;
            $skrevet_af = $_SESSION["navn"] . " " . $_SESSION["efternavn"];
            $emne = implode($_POST["point"]);
            $dato = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            /* Eksekver forespørgslen */
            $stmt->execute();

            echo "ok";

            $stmt->close();

        }
        }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
}
}
?>
```

and i have try :

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST["opret"]))
{
if($_POST["title"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at skrive title!";
}
elseif($_POST["tekst"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at skrive tekst!";
}
elseif($_POST["kategori"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at angive kategori!";
}
elseif($_POST["point"] == "")
{
    echo "Husk at angive point!";
}
elseif(count(array_diff(explode(",", $_POST["kategori"]), array("Frontend", "Backend", "Design"))))
{
    echo "error";
}
else
{
$arr = array(60, 40, 20, 10);
$point = implode($_POST["point"]);

    if(in_array($point, $arr))
    {
        if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('UPDATE `bruger` SET `point`= `point` - ? WHERE `id`=?')) { 
            $stmt->bind_param('ii', $point, $id);
            $point = implode($_POST["point"]);
            $id = $_SESSION["id"];
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }



$str = $_POST["title"];
    $from = array("=", "+", "&",'"', "'", " ", "æ", "Æ", "ø", "Ø", "å", "Å");
    $to = array("-", "", "og", "", "", "-", "ae", "Ae", "oe", "Oe", "aa", "Aa");
    $alias = strtolower(str_replace($from, $to, $str));

    if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO artikler (title, tekst, kategori, url, skrevet_af, emne, dato) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)')) { 

        /* Bind parametre */
        $stmt->bind_param('sssssis', $title, $tekst, $kategori, $url, $skrevet_af, $emne, $dato);

        /* Sæt værdier på parametrene */
        $title = $_POST['title']; 
        $tekst = $_POST["tekst"];
        $kategori = implode(",",$_POST["ka

tegori"]);
            $url = $alias;
            $skrevet_af = $_SESSION["navn"] . " " . $_SESSION["efternavn"];
            $emne = implode($_POST["point"]);
            $dato = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            /* Eksekver forespørgslen */
            $stmt->execute();

            ?>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
                window.location.href = "/indhold/";  
            </script> 
            <?php

            $stmt->close();

        } else {
            /* Der er opstået en fejl */
            echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $mysqli->error;
        }
        }
    else
    {
        echo "Du skal ikke snyd!";
    }
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you're trying to achieve, but you can stop the exexution of a script with `die('error!')` instead of `echo('error!')`.

Comment: the before part of the code that is the first example I knew about code, it should I have to come up with an error before going on to the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure that I completely understood what you are trying to do but I thing that what you need is a control variable. Just create some var set to true and set it to false if any of your checks turns out wrong. Another way is to throw exceptions on every missed check and then try catch them. The last one is a better method because it gives you better debugging information and is more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Remove lines from 23rd to 32nd and put this code in 20th line.

```
elseif(count(array_diff(explode(",", $_POST["kategori"]), array("Frontend", "Backend", "Design"))))
{
    echo "error";
}
```